# Getting session variables from IP.Suite in Angular 2

Tags: php, angular, ipb

I'm working on an Angular 2 project, but now I have to get currently logged in user from IP.Suite (if the user is logged in there) and fetch variables like his ID etc.

I tried asking on their forums, but no one answered. I first thought of fetching the cookie, but it's flagged as HttpOnly. Now, would it work fine if I do a http request to a PHP script and get session variables from there? If so, how?

Thanks in advance.